# Python Pandas resampling data values at regular interval without averaging

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data file:

```
time,value
10:23:10.001103,29.3
10:23:10.002117,29.4
10:23:10.005137,29.7
10:23:10.006203,29.5
10:23:10.007253,29.6
10:23:10.008313,30.2
10:23:10.020323,30.4
10:23:10.030403,30.1
10:23:10.040404,30.2
10:23:10.050503,30.8
10:23:10.060504,30.7
10:23:10.060603,30.9
10:23:10.060703,31.4
10:23:10.060801,31.1
10:23:10.060821,31.2
10:23:10.060921,32.3
```

And I want to resample the data every 5 milliseconds to obtain the following output:

```
time
10:23:10.001103    29.3
10:23:10.006103    29.7
10:23:10.011103    30.2
10:23:10.016103    30.2
10:23:10.021103    30.4
10:23:10.026103    30.4
10:23:10.031103    30.1
10:23:10.036103    30.1
10:23:10.041103    30.2
10:23:10.046103    30.2
10:23:10.051103    30.8
10:23:10.056103    30.8
10:23:10.061103    32.3
```

How do I achieve that?  Basically I want to get the latest seen value on a regular interval.  I tried to use the resample method on the pandas dataframe column but somehow it is averaging all the values within each 5-millisecond bucket.  The code below shows what I was trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'], 'ms')
df2 = df.set_index(df['time'])['value'].resample('5ms').ffill()
print(df2)
```

Comment: Why do you think `.resample('5ms').ffill()` is for average data? I test it and it forward filling them, not average.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I was using python 2.x with pandas version 0.17.1 and it didn't work as expected.  After switching to python 3.x with pandas version 0.18.0 it worked ok.